# Is it possible to unify this expression and its special case into one?

Tags: notation

I have the following expression $\forall n  \ge 1 \in \Bbb N, f(n) \ge 2 \in \Bbb N$:

> $$E = f(n)-1$$

$f(n)$ is a increasing function. The value $f(1)$ is a special case, its value can be $2$ or $3$. In the case that $f(1)=2$ I just want $E = f(1) = 2$, and in the case that $f(1)=3$ I would like to use the general expression $E = f(n)-1$, so $E=f(1)-1=2$. So basically I would like $f(1)$ to be always $2$ independently of $f(1)$.

So if possible I would like to have only one expression, specifically avoiding definitions-by-case, like this one:

> $E = f(n)+$(some nice notation able to unify the general case and the special case)

Valid for any value of $n$ including the special cases of $f(1)$.

I was thinking about something like this:

> $$E = f(n) + \frac{\mid 2-f(n) \mid}{2-f(n)}$$

That will work for $n \gt 2$ and also for the case $n=1$ when $f(1)=3$ but I am not sure if it is valid for the case $n=1$ when $f(1)=2$ (not sure if $\frac{\mid 2-f(n) \mid}{2-f(n)}$ can be evaluated as $0$ for $f(1)=2$).

> Is there a notation able to unify the expressions into one? $f(1)=2$ is an special case. Initially I do not think it is possible but there might be a notation capable of doing it and I do not see it. Thank you!

Comment: @dxiv good suggestion, thank you! I have added that I am not looking for definitions-by-case, just one single expression covering all the possible cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E=f(n)-1\,+\,\delta_{n,1}\, \delta_{f(n),2}$$

This uses the [Kronecker delta.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

However, I don't necessarily recommend doing this.  The point of writing is clarity, and it's probably clearer to write something like this in cases.

Comment: wow! many thanks! nice trick. I see, so an expression like the one I was writing in the question is not possible... By the way, I was trying to explain in my question that $f(n)$ can only be $2$ when $n=1$, so your nice expression finally will be $E=f(n)-1\,+\, \delta_{f(n),n+1}$

Comment: If $f(n)$ can only be 2 when $n=1,$ you can just write $E=f(n)-1+\delta_{f(n),2}.$

Comment: that is totally right! this was the question I was writing, thank you for helping me to wrap-up the special case! http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1941765/189215

Comment: I should have added that your formula with $\frac{\mid 2-f(n) \mid}{2-f(n)}$ doesn't work because when $f(n)=2,$ you get $\frac{0}{0},$ which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

$$E = \mathbf{1}_{\{1\}} \cdot 2 + (1-\mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}) \cdot (f(n) - 1)$$ will do that (where $\mathbf{1}_X$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $X$), though honestly I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: thank you for the proposal, I am writing another bigger question and I needed to wrap-up the special case before asking it.